# Validate Camunda BPM in Eclipse

Tags: camunda

Is there a way to validate BPM in Eclipse before deploying (other than writing JUnit test case)

Regards,
Phani

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the camunda modeler plugin and you want to validate bpmn files you can do the following:

1. right click on the bpmn file in the project explorer
2. select **Validate**
3. open the **Problems** view (click **Window** --> **show view** --> **Problems**)

You will get warnings as result of the validation.

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work properly. Say for example, if there is a EOR gateway, and if the conditions are not defined and validates, it prompts as valid, even though it is not valid. This is a big disadvantage.

Comment: The level of validation is very low, that is correct.